# Merging rows in align environment

Tags: equations, align, vertical-alignment, subequations

I'm looking for a way to merge two rows in an (amsmath) align environment. Here is what I'm trying to achieve (photoshopped):

[image: goal]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \boldsymbol{c}(k+1) &= \boldsymbol{A}_{c} \boldsymbol{c}(k) + \boldsymbol{B}_{y} \boldsymbol{y}_{i} , 
      \qquad t_{i} / h \leq k < t_{i+1} / h \\
    \boldsymbol{u}_i &= \boldsymbol{C}_{c} \boldsymbol{c}(k) + \boldsymbol{D}_{y} \boldsymbol{y}_{i} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I've tried various things, including putting the different part of the equation in tables, but it seems the difficulty is that I want to have a seperate line number for both of these equations, and that I want the numbering to show up on the most right-hand side of the page.

This is my first question on StackExchange, so if I'm missing something aplogies in advance :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I augmented this answer after receiving additional information from the OP.)

I'd like to suggest a slight rearrangement of the material, as shown in the first group of equations in the following screenshot. That way, you introduce `k` *before* it gets used in a couple of equations. (Incidentally, shouldn't `k` itself be indexed to `i`, i.e., expressed as `k_i`?)

If you absolutely, positively *must* place the explanatory material right next to the equations in question, I suggest you proceed as is done in the second set of equations shown below. (The answer assumes tha there are two subequations. If there are three subequations, it's much more straightforward to just place the explanatory directly on the middle row.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
%% for use in the second set of equations:
\newcommand\specialnote[1]{\smash{%
      \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
               \\[3pt] % empty line
               #1 
      \end{array}
      }}

\begin{document}

For $k\in[t_i/h,t_{i+1}/h)$ (or: ``For $t_{i}/h \leq k < t_{i+1}/h$''), we have:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \bm{c}(k+1) &= \bm{A}_{c} \bm{c}(k) + \bm{B}_{y} \bm{y}_{i}  \\
    \bm{u}_i    &= \bm{C}_{c} \bm{c}(k) + \bm{D}_{y} \bm{y}_{i} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Or: 
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \bm{c}(k+1) &= \bm{A}_{c} \bm{c}(k) + \bm{B}_{y} \bm{y}_{i}  
    \qquad\specialnote{t_{i}/h \leq k < t_{i+1}/h} \\
    \bm{u}_i    &= \bm{C}_{c} \bm{c}(k) + \bm{D}_{y} \bm{y}_{i} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for the reply! :) The suggestion you give is how I have things currently, but I guess it’s my style preference (also in line with various other piecewise/hybrid systems definition used in my Thesis/literature) to include the piecewise definition in a more “centralised” manner, inside the equation (without having to read the proceeding or ensuing text). As with regards to your other suggestion, I think using $$k$$ gives an inequality of the form $$10 \leq k < 15$$, which is what I try to convey (also I use $$k_i = t_i /h$$). Thanks for your interest! :)

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel - I've modified my answer to provide a suggestion for how the information about the piecewise definition might be "centralised".

Comment: Epic, thank you so much! The `\smash` command was exactly what I was looking for, great to know it exists :) I've accepted your answer